# Whats the correct way to change DB prefixes in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, catalogsearch

I made a mistake and left out the _ between the prefix and the table name in our new Magento 2 site. So I manually changed the table names to include it. 
Now none of our products show in any search results.

They do show in the New Products widget on the homepage, but if I search it just returns a blank page with the layered navigation.

So I'm guessing I screwed up by manually editing the table names.

What would be the correct way to have done this?

Comment: Did you reindex everything again?

Comment: Yep,  bin/magento reindex:indexer

Comment: revert the table name?

Comment: I guess thats the next step. Just thought that there might be a better way.

Comment: can you mention where did you make mistake in table name?

Comment: In the prefix. Instead of xxx_table_name, i forgot the _ and it ended up as xxxtable_name.

Comment: You can try [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-deployment.html), which should enable you to fix the DB configuration. You can also look in `app/etc/env.php` to see if the DB prefix is stored there. _Back everything up first_

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot this morning, once the back ups done. Cheers.